# How to use restclient dropbox API with NSURLSessionDownloadTask to download files

Tags: ios, dropbox, nsurlsession

Problem: i want to download a file from my dropbox account and use quick look to visualize it.

First Solution:

1) use Dropbox API restClient:

```
[[self restClient] loadFile:fullpath intoPath:finalpath];
```

2) Once downloaded use QLPreviewController to preview the file.

The problem with this solution is that I don't know how to synchronize the download with the preview (to use quick look the file needs to be local, so I need to download it first).

The (ugly) workaround I came up with is to set up an alert ("Caching") and make it last an arbitrary length of time (let's say 12 sec, magic number...). At the same time I pause execution for 10-12 seconds (magic numbers):

[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:12.0f];

...and hope at the end of this time interval the file is downloaded already so I can start the QLPreviewController.

Here is the code (ugly, I know....):

```
// Define Alert
UIAlertView *downloadAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"caching" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil] ;

// If  file does not exist alert downloading is ongoing
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:finalpath])
{
    // Alert Popup
    [downloadAlert show];
    //[self performSelector:@selector(isExecuting) withObject:downloadAlert afterDelay:12];

}

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //Here your non-main thread.
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:finalpath])
    {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:12.0f];
    }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // Dismiss alert
        [downloadAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex: -1 animated:YES];

        //Here we return to main thread.
        // We use the QuickLook APIs directly to preview the document -
        QLPreviewController *previewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
        previewController.dataSource = self;
        previewController.delegate = self;
        // Push new viewcontroller, previewing the document
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:previewController animated:YES];

    });
        });
```

It does work (with small files and fast connection) but It's not the best solution... .

I think that the best solution would be integrate NSURLSession with dropbox restClient so to use this routine:

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration
                                                        delegate:nil
                                                   delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
  NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task;
  task = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request
                        completionHandler:^(NSURL *localfile, NSURLResponse *response, NSErr or *error) {
/* yes, can do UI things directly because this is called on the main queue */ }];
  [task resume];
```

But I'm not sure how to use it with the DropBox API: any suggestion ?

Thanks,
     dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the API tells you about progress and completion:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedFile:(NSString*)destPath contentType:(NSString*)contentType metadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata;
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadProgress:(CGFloat)progress forFile:(NSString*)destPath;
```

No need to do any sleeping or gcd calls directly.  Just change your UI to show busy when  the download starts and use these to update UI with progress and completion.